# JOOQ: How to add a returning clause when updating through record

Tags: kotlin, jooq

I am currently updating table by using:

```
fun <T: MyRecordInterface<*>> updateRecord(record: T) {
   record.setField1("field1")
   record.setField2("field2")

   record.update()
}
```

That allow to update different types of record that share the same interface:

```
updateRecord(myRecord1Instance)
updateRecord(myRecord2Instance)
```

I would like to return the full updated record after update, so I did:

```
fun <T: MyRecordInterface<*>> updateRecord(record: T): T {
   record.setField1("field1")
   record.setField2("field2")

   record.update()
   record.refresh()

   return record
}
```

Is it possible to add returning clause to the update query so that I will not have to issue 2 query in this method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn on `Settings.returnAllOnUpdatableRecord` globally, which will fetch all the resulting values (identities, trigger-generated values, etc.) automatically for you on every `store()`, `insert()`, `update()` call.

This is applied globally, and incurs some overhead, especially if you do not want those resulting values, so it may make sense to use a new `Configuration` with the above `Settings` only where this is really needed.